# Can't download and read file from azure that has empty spaces in file name

Tags: java, azure-files

I am trying to download a file with the following name: `Some_name random 15 + 17.pdf`. When I am trying to read from this file I am getting the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateFromHttpStatus(StorageException.java:175)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:94)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.downloadAttributes(CloudFile.java:1492)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.openRead(CloudFile.java:1819)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.CloudFile.openRead(CloudFile.java:1785)
at ch.prestige.tools.dossier.microservice.service.impl.AzureFileClientProvider.readFileContent(AzureFileClientProvider.java:166)
```

This is the code that I am using to download the file:

```
public AzureFile downloadFileFromFileShare(String fileName, String fileLocation) {
    getFile();
    final CloudFileClient fileClientReference = getFileClientReference();
    CloudFile cloudFile;
    try {
        final CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClientReference.getShareReference(fileLocation);
        cloudFile = fileShare.getRootDirectoryReference().getFileReference(fileName);
        log.info("Downloaded file: {} from azure file share", fileName);
        return new AzureFile(fileName, readFileContent(cloudFile));
    } catch (URISyntaxException | StorageException e) {
        log.error("Failed to retrieve file for document {}", fileName, e);
        throw new AzureFileStorageNotAvailableException("Failed to retrieve file");
    }
}
```

and for reading the content:

```
private ByteArrayResource readFileContent(CloudFile cloudFile) {
    try (final FileInputStream fileInputStream = cloudFile.openRead()) {
        final byte[] content = fileInputStream.readAllBytes();
        return new ByteArrayResource(content);
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        log.error("The specified file {} does not exist", cloudFile.getUri(), e);
        throw new AzureFileStorageNotAvailableException("The specified file " + cloudFile.getUri() + " does not exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to read file content of {}", cloudFile.getUri(), e);
        throw new AzureFileStorageNotAvailableException("Failed to read file content of " + cloudFile.getUri());
    }
}
```

As I was debugging in the library of azure I notice that is changing the name to:

```
https://Some_name%20random%2015%20+%2017.pdf
```

Is there any chance for a file with this kind of name to be retrieved. For the other files that I have upload download seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the latest version of the package, such as：

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
      <version>8.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

If this still does not solve your problem, please follow the naming convention provided by the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Shares--Directories--Files--and-Metadata#directory-and-file-names) to name your file, which can also be used as a solution to circumvent your problem:

[image]

Comment: It's not helping, I am still getting the same exception. My methods are working with files that are not following this syntax but the issue is that I am not in control of the files. I can't understand why Azure is allowing you to upload this file (not via java but using their UI) and then you are not allowed to download them.